# How do you use multiprocessing in Python and pass multiple arguments while also knowing which number of process is occuring?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to get the number of process is currently happening. I know I can do the following.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(args):

    print("process number "+str(args))
    
SLICES = 8
with Pool(SLICES) as p:
    p.map(f, range(SLICES))
```

Which yields:

```
process number 0
process number 2
process number 1
process number 3
process number 7
process number 5
process number 4
process number 6
```

I gather that the argument `args` passed when called will give out which numbers of processes is occurring. I know that in order to pass multiple arguments to the multiprocess, you have to put it in the form of array, or object, or tuple, etc. But when I pass multiple arguments in the form of array, I suddenly can no longer access which number of multiprocesses is occurring. For example here,

```
def f(args):
    return(args[0]+args[1])
    
SLICES = 8
with Pool(SLICES) as p:
    matrices = np.random.random ([16,2]) * 10
    matrices = matrices.astype(int)
    print(matrices)
    
    result = p.map(f,matrices)
    print(result)
```

Results to:

```
[[5 4]
 [9 5]
 [8 5]
 [8 9]
 [8 9]
 [7 4]
 [2 4]
 [7 4]
 [7 6]
 [3 9]
 [4 0]
 [9 3]
 [7 1]
 [5 5]
 [6 8]
 [8 0]]
[9, 14, 13, 17, 17, 11, 6, 11, 13, 12, 4, 12, 8, 10, 14, 8]
```

Now I can no longer access the number of processes that are occurring. My concern is I still want to pass multiple arguments but also still able to access the number processes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding the question, as I'm not totally sure I know what you mean by "process number".  Since in your first example, it's simply an id you created and passed to the function, you can still do that, just make it part of the arguments you pass in.

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

def f(args):
    # index is the "id" or number you pass in that numbers the process.
    # arr is the np.random.random matrix that is passed in.
    index, arr = args
    # Do things with index.
    print(f"hello from {index}") 
    # Or pass it back...or don't.
    return (index, (arr[0] + arr[1]))
    # return arr[0] + arr[1]


SLICES = 8
with Pool(SLICES) as p:
    matrices = np.random.random([16, 2]) * 10
    matrices = matrices.astype(int)
    print(matrices)

    result = p.map(f, ((idx, val) for idx, val in enumerate(matrices)))
    print(result)
```

Results in:

```
[[5 1]
 [5 8]
 [5 4]
 [2 2]
 [9 5]
 [7 7]
 [8 4]
 [6 8]
 [0 5]
 [5 6]
 [8 6]
 [4 2]
 [0 7]
 [3 0]
 [5 3]
 [6 7]]
[(0, 6), (1, 13), (2, 9), (3, 4), (4, 14), (5, 14), (6, 12), (7, 14), (8, 5), (9, 11), (10, 14), (11, 6), (12, 7), (13, 3), (14, 8), (15, 13)]
```

Comment: I need to be able to access the process number from inside the function f and do something like printing it and storing it to a variable. In your code, you just enumerate it, but I still can't access it from inside the f() function.

Comment: You do access it from f.  That's the `index` argument that you are returning (though of course you don't have to return it...you could do whatever you want).

Comment: have you tried to run the code? Idk why but when I run it in my jupyter notebook it seemed to be running indefinitely.

Comment: I did.  The output is from my run (or my original run before the edit that added the print statements, but I've re-run it and it ends).  The only thing different between what you had and what I'm suggesting is simply adding the index as part of the arguments.  You don't have to use my implementation of it, but if your example works in the notebook, then start there and add a counter/process number/whatever to the arguments you pass in and go from there.